# D3js build svg grid with rows and columns align rectangle box in center of the grid row

Tags: d3.js

I need to create a svg gird with boxes from the given input.
I am trying to solve this following task. I need an help to solve this rendering boxes issues.

- The boxes should center aligned to each row with cell spacing.
- Need to set view port to svg. Boxes should be hidden on overflow. Need drag to cursor to view the hidden box.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test1.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <input type="text" name="rows" id="rows" placeholder="Enter No of Rows" />
    <input type="text" name="columns" id="columns" placeholder="Enter No of Columns"/>
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button" id="generate">Generate</button>
    <h2>D3.js Highlight area with</h2>
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.17/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    const w=400;
const h=400;

const rows = d3.select('#rows');
const columns = d3.select('#columns');
d3.select('#generate').on('click',function(){
    var grid = [columns.attr('value'),rows.attr('value')];
    var box = [Math.round(w/grid[0]),Math.round(h/grid[1])];
});

d3.select('#rows').attr('value',10);
d3.select('#columns').attr('value',10);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```